# What's the easiest way to print out the contents of a singly String linked list in a JFrame Window?

Tags: java, swing

I wrote my linked list class from scratch (didn't import the one Java has).

I've thought about making multiple JPanels and adding a string to each panel from my linked list (each node has a string), then adding all of the JPanels to the main JFrame window to accomplish this. Is this the most straightforward way?

Comment: Have you though about using a [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)? You'd be able to just append the String on each node of your LinkedList to it. Plus you can customize it so that it doesn't look like a JTextArea.

Comment: @hwdbc: no, much better to use a JList and to make the OP's "list" the model for the JList by either having it implement ListModel or by wrapping it in a class that does. It would then be passed directly into the JList and would display.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's a pretty good point. I agree that OP should disregard JTextArea and look into JList.

Comment: I like the `JList` and wrapper idea.  I think perhaps just a list of `JLabel` might be "simple."  `JTextArea` is interesting too: just have the list implement a normal `toString()` method and stuff the result of that into a `JTextArea`.